# Do HTML5 videos keep computer on?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, html5-video, mp4, webm

This might sound a little odd, but **I was curious if HTML5 `<video>` tags are meant to keep your computer "awake" or prevent it from turning off somehow way while playing.** I know that would be the *expected* behaviour considering it's a video and you wouldn't want your screen to turn off, but upon Googling it most of the results ended up being people *seeking to try and keep the screen on*, which leads me to believe that by default it doesn't. I only started exploring this because I've noticed when leaving my page open, the computer does in fact stay awake.

This is how I've implemented the video:

```
<video autoplay="autoplay" class="header-video" id="header-video" loop="loop" muted="muted" preload="preload">
    <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4"></source>
    <source src="video.webm" type="video/webm"></source>
 </video>
```

And I've noticed this happening on my iMac in Chrome.

**Edit**

Below are my power settings - note that this is default from a fresh install of Mavericks. I guess I'm curious because I'd like to know if, by default, people should be *aware* about whether or not their computer will stay awake. It could be a pretty big issue in terms of energy consumption.

[image]

Comment: Have you check your power options ? There is probably some stuff in advanced options that keeps computer from sleep or turning off while video is playing

Comment: I've updated my answer with my Energy Saver settings :)

Answer (score 1):

I think this is default behavior from the operating system for videos. I was reviewing some power options and sleep options and apple specifically noted that the options are changed during videos and dvds so that it doesnt sleep. 
Check it out
[Apple Support - Mac not sleeping during video](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1776)

Comment: That's interesting! I mean, I would expect it from a DVD, or even a third-party browser extension (such as Silverlight or Flash), but I wouldn't expect that a native browser element could control a computer's setting like that.

Comment: Yea Crazy.. bet if you pause the video it will sleep.

Comment: True! Though, this video was actually developed to be the background of a header, so it continuously loops.